# Is there a linux command that will read a certain number of characters including control chars?

Tags: linux, terminal, stdin

I want to be able to read 10 characters of keyboard input for example, and store them into a file.  I tried the linux command:

```
read -n 10
```

But it aborts if you hit ctrl-c (0x03).  I need to be able to read the next 10 characters no matter what they are, including all control characters, so values 0x00 through 0xFF.  Is this possible?

Comment: Your command will successfully read a 0x03 character if one is input. However, Ctrl-C will by default send a sigint and will not input a 0x03 character. What's the use case for this?

Comment: I want to invent a proprietary way for a terminal emulator application to transfer a file to remote host.  Basically the terminal emulator would tell the linux side to go into a special mode where it mimics that the user typed out the contents of the file, and the remote linux site would store those bytes to create the file on the remote side.  This would be sort of like how terminal printing works with <ESC>[4i, <ESC>[5i, but in the opposite direction.

Comment: You should be able to just dump arbitrary binary data and read it with e.g. `cat > file`. Sending a 0x03 byte is not the same as pressing Ctrl-C.

Comment: Try this: `saved=$(stty -g);stty raw pass8;dd of=/your/output/file bs=1 count=10 2>/dev/null;stty $saved`

Comment: @MarkPlotnick it seems like that works!  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the behavior of the control characters by (temporarily!) putting your terminal into raw mode.  That will let it read whatever is available.  But reading a *specified* number of characters is going to be subject to whatever `bash` decides to do in this case.

xterm for instance has several reasonably portable shell scripts which set the terminal into raw mode and read back the response from the terminal for various queries (such as the current fontname).  In the scripts that looks like this:

```
exec </dev/tty                       
old=`stty -g`  
stty raw -echo min 0  time 5

$CMD $OPT "${ESC}]4;4;?^G${SUF}" > /dev/tty
read original
stty $old
original=${original}${SUF}

if ( trap "echo exit" EXIT 2>/dev/null ) >/dev/null
then
    trap '$CMD $OPT "$original" >/dev/tty; exit' EXIT HUP INT TRAP TERM
else
    trap '$CMD $OPT "$original" >/dev/tty; exit' 0    1   2   5    15
fi
```

although you would have to read the whole script to see how it all works.  That was from `acolors.sh` (see [sources](http://invisible-island.net/datafiles/release/xterm.tar.gz)).

Bear in mind also that even if you set the terminal to read a given number of characters, that (unless you enforce no timeout), then you will get just what the terminal has provided.  This can be less, and (for instance recalling some debugging code in ncurses), programs which read terminal responses have to handle incomplete reads along with timeouts.